# Confusion over solution to Linear Transformation from P2 to P3

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations

I'm trying to understand the solution to the question below. I warrant I'm probably confused over the notation.

In the question (attached below) it says that transformation T(p)[x] = xp(x-3), with standard basis for P2 and P3.

I assume you need to break it down into:

Po = 1 + 0x + 0x^2

P1 = 0 + 1x + 0x^2

P2 = 0 + 0x + x^2

And apply the transformation to each Pn. However, I have no idea how you would do that stepwise when the transformation is defined by xp(x-3).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[Polynomial Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey5E9.png)

Comment: $T(p_0)[x]=xp_0(x-3)=x$, $T(p_1)[x]=xp_1(x-3)=x(x-3)$, $T(p_2)[x]=xp_2(x-3)=x(x-3)^2$

Comment: I don't really understand why what you have written is valid, and that is what I am asking for help with. Because assuming we want the zeroth polynomial of (x-3), I know the zeroth polynomial of x is 1, but what happens to that 3? And how does that transpose to the other polynomials?

Comment: $p_0(t)=1$ for all $t$, whether $t=x$ or $t=x-3$; $p_1(t)=t$, so $p_1(x-3)=x-3$

Comment: Oh ok, that makes a bit more sense. And that is applied to all other polynomials? So p1(x-3) = x, and p2(x-3) = x^2?

Comment: $p_2(t)=t^2$, so $p_2(x-3)=(x-3)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to change basis, the columns of the transformation matrix are made up by applying the transformation on each element of the basis of your domain space, to get the corresponding column of your transformation matrix when expressed in the basis of $P3$.

Now the standard domain of $P2$ is $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0) ,(0,0,1)\}$ where each element represents the coefficient of $1, x, x^2$ respectively

Now, let these "vectors" be $P_1, P_2, P_3$ (as each represents a polynomial)

Hence, $T(P_1) = xP_1(x-3) = x = (0,1,0,0)$

$T(P_2) = xP_2(x-3) = x(x-3) = x^2-3x = (0,-3,1,0)$

$T(P_3) = xP_3(x-3) = x((x-3)^2) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 9x = (0,9,-6,1)$

Hence, we can write the standard matrix representation of the transformation T as

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -3 & 9 \\ 0 & 1 & -6 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That was really clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is defined by $$T(p)(x)=xp(x-3),$$
and we need to find the image of the standard basis vectors (of $\mathbf P^2$)  under $T$, in terms of the standard basis of the image space $\mathbf P^3$. So we need to separately compute $T(p_0),T(p_1),T(p_2)$ and see how we can express this as a linear combination of $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$. For example, $$T(p_1)(x)=xp_1(x-3)=x(x-3)=x^2-3x=p_2(x)-3p_1(x).$$
(Because $p_2(x):=x^2$ and $p_1(x):=x$.) Can you figure out how to do the rest?

Comment: Why does 1(−3) = (−3)? This is where I am confused about the notation. Does that also mean 2(−3) = (−3)? I don't understand the second equality and how to apply that to higher polynomials.

Comment: If 1(x) = (x) and 1(x-3) = (x-3), does 2(x) = x^2 imply 2(x-3) = x^2+9?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I just realised that you have to apply the proper expansion. I'm sorry if this was obvious, but it wasn't really explained when I was learning it. For the sake of argument, assuming the transformation was from 3 to 4, the next transformation would be x^4 - 9x^3 + 27x^2 -27x?

Comment: @cthodrums By definition, $p_1(x)=x$. The given transformation takes an input polynomial $p$, and transforms it to a new one given by $xp(x-3)$. In words, you substitute $x-3$ into the original polynomial, then multiply by $x$. So the polynomial $p_1(x)=x$ will become $x-3$ after the substitution, and now you multiply by $x$ to get $x(x-3)=x^2-3x$.

Comment: @cthodrums If now we consider $p_2(x)=x^2$, applying the transformation we have $T(p_2)(x)=xp_2(x-3)$. So we have $x(x-3)^2 = x(x^2-6x+9)=x^3-6x^2+9x$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That clears up a lot!

Comment: @cthodrums No problem!